# All certificates are not listing while creating Provisoning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

When I am trying to create a provisioning profile,the certificate which is used to create the push notification is not listing.but it is listing in AppID section.Any idea ?

Comment: please add screenshot..

Comment: Certificate not relates to app id instead App id relates to certificate means it is not necessary that app id exist then the same certificate will be exist for sure.

Comment: @ArpitKumarKulshrestha : You'r right, put as answer with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a step by step process of making certificate which include following process given below :-

1. Make a certificate with CSR (Independent of App Id)
2. Make App Id (Should be unique)
3. Add device id's (On which app required to be run)
4. Last, make provision profile which needs above three things too means    certificate , app id and device id's.

So If you can see App id in your list of App id's and not the certificate it means simple Certificate not relates to app id instead App id relates to certificate with respect to the provision profile.And it is not necessary that app id exist then the same certificate will be exist for sure.